# Question about the validity of the use of induction in this case.

Tags: induction, set-theory

I'm working through Thomas Jech's Set Theory book, and am stuck on a point in exercise 1.3.

Here he introduces the naturals. First he defines the set $N$ as $\bigcap \{X : X \text{ is inductive}\}$, that is as the smallest inductive set.

Then he mentions the following notation,

$ 0 = \varnothing, 1 = \{0\}, 2 = \{0,1\}, \ldots$

and writes that if $n \in N$, then $n+1 = n \cup \{n\}$ which obviously belongs to $N$, as it is inductive (note that we can't even claim that these are the only elements of $N$. Or can we, at this point?)

Now he asks to prove that for any inductive $X$, the set $S = \{x \in X : x \subset X\}$ is also inductive, which is trivial. Hence $N$ is also transitive. But the tag question bugs me, where he asks to prove that $n = \{m \in N : m < n\}$. ($<$ is defined by $\in$).

To me the only way to show this appears to be to assume that it is valid for $n$ and prove for $n+1$, which is induction, and which I cannot really use at this point.

Also, the question asks a question about $n$, which is only defined conditionally (if "$n-1$" $\in N$), so unless we prove the theorem of induction, we cannot really assume that $n$ is well defined from the only concrete fact that $0 = \varnothing \in N$.

Am I right in this reasoning?

Comment: Can't you just prove that $\{n\in N\mid n=\{m\in N\mid m<n\}\}$ is an inductive set? I don't see why not.

Comment: Okay, so since $S = \{n \in N | n = \{m \in N | m < n \} \}$ is inductive, and $\subset N$, so $S = N$, proving this for all $n \in N$. Now in the proof assuming that $n \in S$ we get that $n = \{m \in N | m < n \}$, we need to to show $n+1 = n \cup \{n\}$ also satisfies this. Now clearly, $n+1 \in N$, and if $x \in n+1$, then either $x = n$, or $x \in n$, in both cases the rest is trivial. Did I get your point right?

Comment: Yes. Based on $n\in N\wedge n=\{m\in N\mid m<n\}$ it can be shown that $n+1=n\cup{n}=\{m\in N\mid m\leq n\}=\{m\in N\mid m<n+1\}$. Also $n+1\in N$ so we arrive at $n+1\in S$.

Comment: If you read the exercise carefully, it states that $<$ is defined on $N$. When is states $n$ you should not see this as a reference to some meta-theoretical concept of a specific number (whatever that may be), but simply as some element of $N$. Hence the fact that $n=\{m\in N : m<n\}$ is just an immediate corollary of the transitivity of $N$. Induction comes in the next chapter. :p

Comment: $N$ is transitive. So any element is also a subset. $n$ is an element. So $n$ is a subset. But how does that imply that $n$ is that specific subset $\{m \in N : m \in n\}$

Comment: Well $n =n\cap N$ because $n\subset N$, but also $n\cap N = \{m \mid m\in N \land m\in n\} = \{m\in N \mid m\in n\}$

Comment: Oh, thats great. :o One last thing, can we also do something about the fact that we don't know whether these $n$'s are the only elements of $N$.

Comment: I mean we define $n+1 = n \cup \{n\}$ if $n \in N$, but could we be not omitting some elements of $N$, that cannot be generated in this fashion?  (I mean I know we're not, but how do we prove that?)

Comment: By the way, please make one an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, starting from $0$ and just adding successors won't give you all of $N$ in nonstandard models, but I think Jech mentions it at some point